# Google Store Beta, Increment Version Each Time?

Tags: android, google-play

When using the beta channel (or alpha, for that matter), does each new version of the beta APK that I upload have to have a higher version number than the previously uploaded APK? I assume that yes, it does, even though that kinda breaks my current versioning schema.

Oh well, not the first time I've had to rethink it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. Beta channel uses the same mechanism to determine if update is available - so, you must bump `versionCode` if you wish your application to be updated.

As beta versions are able to become a stable ones "in one click" - you must numerate your beta- and release- versions in single monotonously increased sequence.

Comment: Thanks. As I was typing the question the answer sort of clicked with me as to how it works.